# Review page gives me 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-page

Anyone is noticing a problem on [DA review page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/)? It currently gives me a 404 error.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does anyone have a repro here ... having trouble reproducing

Comment: Also if you log out do you see the review page, is this affecting all browsers  ?

Comment: If I logged out I can see the review page, if I logged back in I can't see it anymore. Happens in Chrome and FF too (3.6.18) and also in 2 different location (work and home). I'm connected using my gmail account.

Comment: must be related to your prefs on your account can you try this link: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day

Comment: my guess is that we are setting you to the suggested edit tab which you have no access to ... will fix

Comment: Yep the link you send me is working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now ... thanks for reporting it.